# How to convert video from H.264 to H.265 in c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ffmpeg

I want to convert .mp4 h264  to .mp4 h265 video using c# code.
I have tried it before using ffmpeg but i cannot do  it.   . 
Please reply i need it.
Please describe.

Comment: just in case this is an example with FFmpeg `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4`

Comment: @nbari 
Thanks for your response

Comment: I have done it using  this Code But Its Not Working
         Please Give Details in C#

Answer (score 1):

I have solved This Issue By Using Stack overflow.
Here Is a Solution.[How to convert video from H.264 to H.265 Using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44006400/7546324)

By Following and Understanding It You will Reach To Your Goal